# Como voltar versão do aplicativo na App Store?

Tags: ios, app, apple, appstore

Eu subi uma versão de um Aplicativo recentemente com várias modificações na **App Store (IOS)**, infelizmente um bug foi para o ar, então a melhor solução no momento é voltar para a última versão estável, que estava em produção antes dessa.

Então fiquei com a seguinte dúvida.

É possível voltar a versão de um Aplicativo em produção na loja da App Store? Se sim como faço isso?

> Pensei em criar uma nova versão e subir a compilação antiga, mas mesmo
>   assim teria o delay de aprovação da loja e seria uma espécie de
>   gambiarra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível reverter a versão do aplicativo. você deve fazer o upload da versão anterior como nova versão novamente para corrigir isso. Uma coisa que você pode fazer é: "Agilizando uma revisão de aplicativos", verifique o link a seguir que explica bem.

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=expedite

Comment: Muito obrigado Antonius! Infelizmente era o que eu suspeitava kk. Mas esse formulário que me passou acredito que irá me ajudar bastante :D

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é possível, versões de aplicativos são incrementais, ou seja, se você tem um aplicativo `0.0.10` a próxima atualização deve conter uma versão no minimo com a `0.0.11`.

O que você deve fazer é enviar outra versão com o código instável. Lembrando que tem que esperar o período de revisão da apple!

Pode seguir os seguintes passos:

Supondo que você está usando `git`, eu recomendaria você criar um `branch` através do seu `commit` que deseja voltar.

Para saber qual o hash(sha1) do seu `commit`, em seu terminal digite:

```
git log
```

No Visual Studio Code são as partes em amarelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criando uma `branch` através do seu `commit`:

```
git checkout -b branchInstavel 1329102864012a1502f3cbaa5ce9936c78ca2863
```

Após você pode construir seu aplicativo através desse `branch` e enviar novamente para revisão.

Quando conseguir corrigir o `bug` faça um *merge* para a `branch` master.